# How to convert string value to integer?

Tags: android, numberformatexception

```
 String servicePrice = serviceListArrayList.get(position).getPrice();
        System.out.println ("Price======>"+servicePrice);
        price = Integer.parseInt(servicePrice);
        System.out.println("IntPrice====>"+price);
```

I want to convert this servicePrice value to integer value but unfortunately got NumberFormatException,please help me from this error.

Comment: What's the value of `servicePrice`? What format of numbers are you trying to accept?

Comment: You should check it for null value. if the string is Null then this "NumberFormatException" is thron

Comment: servicePrice is a string value i want the summation of servicePrice as it is string value so i need to convert that string value to an integer value

Comment: "_servicePrice is a string value_" What value? "1234"? "12.34"? "abc123"?

Comment: you may add the whole code for more clarification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will get a `NumberFormatException` if `servicePrice` is not a string representation of an integer (e.g. `"1"` or `"123"`). Examples include an empty string (`""`), text (`"abc"`), decimal numbers (`"1.23"`), currencies (`"$1.23"` or `"$2"`), or things that aren't valid numbers (`"1.2.3"` or `"0..1"`)

If you aren't in control of the string, you'll want to use appropriate checks to handle if a bad value is entered

```
int val = 0;
try {
    val = Integer.parseInt(str);
}
catch(NumberFormatException np) {
    // handle the case - e.g. error Toast message
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot to everyone, the problem is there is a blankspace beside the string value that's why numberformatexception arises i solve it by using trim().

Comment: @AbhijitRoy from where this blank space come?

Comment: @AbhijitRoy this is your statement  "String servicePrice = serviceListArrayList.get(position).getPrice();"

Comment: @ Abdulwahid blank space comes from right side like "10     "

Answer (score 0):

The exception **NumberFormatException** is just only because the servicePrice value is not the number String. ( Any string value which is not convertible to as number value)

Better you catch the,   price = Integer.parseInt(servicePrice);

For example

```
try
    {
        price  = Integer.parseInt(servicePrice);
    }
    catch(NumberFormatException ex)
    { // you can assign default as 0 here too.
      price =0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

int price = Integer.parseInt(serviceprice)

Log what value is stored in serviceprice

You can only convert numbers to String not alphabets.
Your serviceListArrayList.get(position).getPrice() might be returning some price with alphabets such as rs or dollars. 
So print serviceprice and check.